# Swift Subclass methods not being recognized

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm working with SpriteKit and I have a subclass written for the SKSpriteNode class.

```
class PlayFieldNode: SKSpriteNode {

    var myFunction: (()->())?

    // other methods

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
        if let f = myFunction {
            f()
        }
    }

}
```

Inside a child node of the PlayFieldNode I want to do,

```
self.parent!.myFunction = self.myFunction
```

When I try to do this, it won't even compile and it gives warning like, `Value of type 'SKNode' has no member 'myFunction'`

I'm relatively new to working with swift, am I missing something involving inheritance or closures? I've double-checked and made sure that the parent is in fact the PlayFieldNode that I want to use.

Comment: How is `self.parent` declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because parent is base `SKNode` class, which knows nothing about your `myFunction`, so you need at first to detect if parent *is-a* your subclass, so use

```
if let parent = self.parent as? PlayFieldNode {
   parent.myFunction = self.myFunction
}
```